# Can't find /dev/ttyUSB1 in ubuntu20.04, did find it in the past

Tags: dual-boot, usb, tty

typing `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` , it print `/dev/ttyUSB0` and `/dev/ttyUSB2`, but I can't find `/dev/ttyUSB1`, I did have it in the past. ttyUSB1 was the serial port connected to my FPGA board, host talks to it via gnu screen. But now it disappears, and I try to talk to board via ttyusb0 and ttyusb2, they don't responde to me.

I think it is related to operation system, I deployed dual system on this laptop. Ubuntu20.04 is installed on external SSD, booted from internal SSD. I can talk to the board via serial terminal( in COM5) in Windows10 pro 1909. I don't if it is windows taking away the port, now I can't find the port in Ubuntu. Any suggestion is welcomed, thank you.

```
$lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05e3:0749 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab13 Seagate RSS LLC OneTouch SSD
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 17ef:60bb Lenovo Lenovo HID Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 291a:8346 SIPODEV Lenovo HID Device
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0403:6010 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT2232C/D/H Dual UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 15ba:002a Olimex Ltd. ARM-USB-TINY-H JTAG interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: It may be `/dev/ttyACM?` instead. Have you tried to monitor device detection by `tail -f /var/log/syslog` ?

Comment: I don't have files like `/dev/ttyACM`, I did find strange printing as `CRON[27946]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)`.

Comment: Now I found that my device is connected to /dev/ttyUSB1, then /dev/ttyUSB2, strange behavior. I have serial output from /dev/ttyUSB2 now, don't know why I didn't get it previously. Thank you for your command of monitor.